# Can iOS apps speak with a builtin library in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

Can iOS apps speak with a builtin library in iOS? Kinda like typing anything on the terminal of a Mac with the "say" command?

i'm planning on building an app with local directions to a place and i want my app itself to navigate the user. Can i make an app that can speak with something more builtin?

Comment: @phix23 Please don't disclose any information that is protected under NDA on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use your app (even when is on the background) for location and navigation purposes, and of course you can play sounds to give them directions.

Check this:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html